# Excel vba to compare values

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 excel sheets sheet A and Sheet B. In Sheet A I have a named range containing Names of employees .Column B  is blank. In sheet 2 I have a named range for a list of employees and days of attendance.The employee names in both sheets are not in the same order. I need to compare the name in sheet A with sheet B and when there is a match I need to copy the attendance days and put it in the Sheet A in column B against the name. I am looking for help in VBA

Any help is appreciated

this is what I have so far

```
    Sub ADDCLM()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Dept_Row As Long
    Dim Dept_Clm As Long
`   Dim table1
    Dim table2
    Dim cl
    table1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A13")
    table2 = Sheet2.Range("A2:A13")
    Dept_Row = Sheet1.Range("B2").Row
    Dept_Clm = Sheet1.Range("B2").Column
    For Each cl In table1
      Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, table2, 2, False)
      Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
    Next cl
    MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? You will get much better help if you post your current efforts and some description of what isn't working.

Comment: Wouldn't VLOOKUP be easier?

Comment: Just use VLOOKUP function. It is designed for this. No need to use VBA unless it's a requirement, in which case **post the code you have already attempted**.

Comment: `=IF(IsNA(Vlookup(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,False)),"not found",VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,False))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, untested. Use range objects instead of variants.  Your row/column counter variables are unnecessary/redundant and I remove them.  You need table2 to be defined as a two column range to use the VLOOKUP function and return the value from column B.  Also, get rid of `On Error Resume Next` that's a bad practice to start, better to use error handling or test for error conditions and re-route.

```
Sub ADDCLM()

Dim table1 As Range
Dim table2 As Range
Dim cl As Range
Set table1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A13")
Set table2 = Sheet2.Range("A2:B13")  '# Modified this to 2 columns
For Each cl In table1
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(cl,table2.columns(1),False) Then
        cl.Offset(0,1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, table2, 2, False)
    End If
Next 
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks when I run your code what happens is it overwrites the value of column A instead of writing to column B.

Comment: Change the line `cl = ...` to `cl.offset(0, 1) = ...`